# C# process cannot run on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a web application that has to open a process and wait for exit. 
This process is a .sh script that uses Cygwin.

I'm using the following code:

```
        var process = new Process();
        var string processFileLocation = @"C:\script.sh";
        var string workingDirectoryLocation = @"C:\script";

        var processInformation = new ProcessStartInfo(processFileLocation)
        {
            WorkingDirectory = workingDirectoryLocation,
            UseShellExecute = true
        };

        process.StartInfo = processInformation;
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();
```

**If I run the application using IISExpress, everything works fine**, the script is being callse.

**When I add it to IIS**, the process simply gets blocked, **I never receive any answer from the request that should call the process**.

I added "Full control" permission to that folder for the Application Pool that the website uses, but still no diference.

Any idea why it is behaving like this?

Comment: When run in an unattended setting, the script generates a prompt and therefore never exits?

Comment: Try running the application pool with an administrator account, to make sure this is not a permission issue

Comment: @KevinGosse thanks man, that worked. I've had some struggles with this and your answer did the trick. Post an answer so I can mark it as 'correct'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever something stops running when put in IIS, there's a high likelihood that it's due to insufficient permissions. Start by running your pool with an administrator account. If it solves the issue, then you can work your way from there to find what permission you were missing.

Comment: Of course, as implied by Kevin, you should never use the `Administrator` account for the production application, only as a tool to determine if lack of permissions is the problem. If so, you should setup an account specifically for the application with *only* the required permissions.